# Function: Error stackTraceLimit: 10 - JavaScript, Google AppScript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, error-handling, runtime-error

Forgive me for my silly questions, I am really a new bee for this coding world.

I have a google app script running on a page where it extracts data from a different sheet. Code so far works fine except it skips few set of code lines and give me an **{ [Function: Error] stackTraceLimit: 10 }** . This skipping part is very important and appreciate id you guys can help.

Thanks. I will post the entire code below.

```
    const bookAId         = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'; // ssId of book A
    const bookBId         = 'yyyyyyyyyyyyy'; // ssId of book B
    const sheetA          = 'RS_Tharalsdson' // name of sheet in book A containing sheet names
    const deadlineRange   = 'G3'; // the cell in book B sheet i that you want to copy - deadline
    const pmsRange        = 'A3' // the cell in book B sheet i that you want to copy - pms
    
    const pmsOnq          = 'onq';
    const pmsFosse        = 'fosse'
    const pmsGalaxy       = 'galaxylightspeed'
    const pmsOpera        = 'opera'
    
    const fileFormatCol   = 4 // column D
    const fileFormatRow   = 6 // first row containing file formats
    const operaCol        = 6 // column F
    const operaRow        = 6 // first row of opera file formats
    
    const subCol          = 5 // submission method column of fosse,onq and galaxy
    const subRow          = 6 // submission starting row of fosse,onq and galaxy
    const subColOpr       = 4 // opera submission col
    const subRowOpr       = 6// opera submission starting row
    
    function getFileFormat(){
      const ssA                   = SpreadsheetApp.openById(bookAId);
      const sA                    = ssA.getSheetByName(sheetA);
      const sheetNames            = sA.getRange('G2:G').getValues().reduce((names, row) =>  row[0] !== '' ? names.concat(row[0]) : names ,[]);
      const ssB                   = SpreadsheetApp.openById(bookBId);
      const fileFormatsFromBookB  = []; // collect the values you find in each sheet
      const submissionMethods       = []; //collect all the submission methods in each sheet   
            
      for (const sheetName of sheetNames) {
        const sheet = ssB.getSheetByName(sheetName);
        
        if (!sheet){
            fileFormatsFromBookB.push(['Sheet Not Found'])
            continue;
        } 
        
        const pmsCell   = sheet.getRange(pmsRange).getValue();
        var array1      = [{}];
        var string2     = pmsCell;
        array1          = string2.split(/[:\n]/);      
        var pms         = array1[1];
        pms             = pms.replace(/\s+/g, '').toLowerCase();
        console.log(sheetName)
        console.log(pms)
        
    
        if(pms==pmsOpera){
          const fileFormatRange = sheet.getRange(operaRow, operaCol, sheet.getLastRow(), 1);
          const fileFormats     = fileFormatRange.getValues();
          var col0              = fileFormats.map(function(value,index) { return value[0]; });     
          const distinct        = (value, index, self) =>{ return self.indexOf(value)===index;}
          var unq               = col0.filter(distinct).toString();
          fileFormatsFromBookB.push([unq]);
    
//ERROR SKIPS BELOW CODE//
          const subMethodsRange = sheet.getRange(subRowOpr, subColOpr, sheet.getLastRow(), 1);
          const subMethods      = subMethodsRange.getValues();
          var col1              = subMethods.map(function(value,index) { return value[0]; });     
          const distinct1       = (value, index, self) =>{ return self.indexOf(value)===index;}
          var unqSub            = col1.filter(distinct1).toString();
          
          submissionMethods.push([unqSub]);
          console.log(Error)
          
        }
    
        if (pms==pmsOnq || pms==pmsFosse || pms==pmsGalaxy) {
    
          const fileFormatRange = sheet.getRange(fileFormatRow, fileFormatCol, sheet.getLastRow(), 1);
          const fileFormats     = fileFormatRange.getValues();
          var col0              = fileFormats.map(function(value,index) { return value[0]; });     
          const distinct        = (value, index, self) =>{ return self.indexOf(value)===index;}
          var unq               = col0.filter(distinct).toString();
          fileFormatsFromBookB.push([unq]);
    
          const subMethodsRange = sheet.getRange(subRow, subCol, sheet.getLastRow(), 1);
          const subMethods      = subMethodsRange.getValues();
          var col1              = subMethods.map(function(value,index) { return value[0]; });     
          const distinct1       = (value, index, self) =>{ return self.indexOf(value)===index;}
          var unqSub            = col1.filter(distinct1).toString();
          submissionMethods.push([unqSub]);
    
        } 
        
        //else {
        //  submissionMethods.push(["__"]);
        //}
       sA.getRange(2, 10, fileFormatsFromBookB.length, 1).setValues(fileFormatsFromBookB); // paste all of the values you collected into the paste range you specified in book
       sA.getRange(2, 11, submissionMethods.length, 1).setValues(submissionMethods); // paste submission methods:unique values
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. Where does the error of `{ [Function: Error] stackTraceLimit: 10 }` occur? 2. Can I ask you about your goal of your script?

Comment: Hi, Error occurs in the code where I commented //ERROR SKIPS BELOW CODE// upto 'submissionMethods.push([unqSub]);'. I don't see anything wrong in the code. But something is there. Purpose is I am trying to get values from two different ranges and and them in two different ranges in a different sheet. Since this involves humongous amount of data I am tryin to trigger functions automatically so sheet will be automated with 100% accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the error. It is actually a typo. I have not been pushing a value to the search array if a the search returns nothing. Code is below.

```
 if (!sheet){
        fileFormatsFromBookB.push(['Sheet Not Found'])
        submissionMethods.push(['Sheet Not Found'])//THIS FIXED THE ISSUE
        continue;
    }
```

Thank you for all the help  guys.